# Visual studio code SFML no such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, sfml

Hello i have been trying to learn c++ SFML by using visual studo code.
After watching a tutorial how to install sfml in c++ i had everything set.
But, the problem is when i try to compile it gives me this error: 
"main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory".
I have been throught many guides but none of them appeared to be working.

Here is my code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1280,720),"Nareszcie");
    while(window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type==sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();

            }
            window.clear();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hope someone will help me in solving this problem.

tasks.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:/mingw32/bin/g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:/mingw32/bin"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "cpp.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\mingw32\\bin\\cpp.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\mingw32\\bin"
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

c_cpp_prperties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/SFML-2.5.1/include/**",
                "C:/SFML-2.5.1"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/mingw32/bin/g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "${default}"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: What build system do you use and what are your compiler flags?

Comment: what .json files should i send.

Comment: You need to add the include directories for SFML. How to do that depends on how you are compiling your project.

Comment: added the json files

Comment: @super what directories i should add?

Comment: You might try `"C:/SFML-2.5.1/include"` instead of `"C:/SFML-2.5.1/include/**"`.

Comment: @BartekDusza The file `c_cpp_properties.json` are for intellisense settings only. You should add the include directory to your build command too.

Comment: @Guillaume Racicot how can i do that?

Comment: @BartekDusza That depends where you installed SFML.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the include directory to your build instructions too.

```
"args": [
    "-g",
    "${file}",
    "-o",
    "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
    "-I",
    "C:/SFML-2.5.1/include/"
],
```

However, you will also need to link your executable to the SFML libraries.

```
"args": [
    "-g",
    "${file}",
    "C:/path/to/sfml/libsfml-graphic.a" // something like that
    "-o",
    "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
    "-I",
    "C:/SFML-2.5.1/include/",
],
```

My recommendation would be to use a proper build system such as CMake, meson or others, which will do this kind of things automatically. Here's a CMake example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(your-project CXX)

# creates your executable with two cpp file in it
add_executable(my-exe main.cpp otherfile.cpp)

# find sfml. Assume the command line argument -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="C:/SFML-2.5.1"
find_package(SFML 2.5.1 COMPONENTS graphic REQUIRED)

# configure your project correctly. Take care of include directories and linking
target_link_libraries(my-exe PUBLIC sfml-graphic)
```

VSCode also has a nice plugin for these build systems.

Comment: Do i need to create a new json file or open an existing one?

Comment: @BartekDusza I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Well i'm quite new and i'm asking in which file i should put the .json code

Comment: @BartekDusza That would be in the compiler arguments in `tasks.json`. However VS code is not a build system. You should equip yourself with proper tools.

Comment: Thank you very much